# Posts, comments and advanced sql filtering

Tags: mysql

I have a database table of posts. I have another db table with comments, with a column for comment_id (ai) and a column for the post_id it's attached to.

I want to make a query list all of my posts *once*, sorted by last posted comment.

The problem is I can't figure out the sql query to do it. Whatever I try I get all the comments listed too. I'm very skilled or experienced with mysql, but I tried using different "joins". Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Post the queries that you tried already. even if they are not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct p.* FROM posts as p, comments as c 
WHERE p.post_id = c.post_id ORDER BY c.time DESC
```

I just assumed your relational schema. You might need to adapt the query.

Alternative: create a view with the last_comment_time as a field.

```
CREATE VIEW posts AS 
(SELECT *, (SELECT time FROM comments WHERE post_id = p.post_id ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1) as last_comment_time
 FROM posts as p);
```

Comment: That worked excellent. I need to look further into sql, this is getting interesting

Comment: I am not sure whether Alex solution might be faster. It contains a subquery which might become inefficient depending on the used DBMS. Unnesting subqueries is not a generalized technique yet. But there is a paper that describes a general unnesting technique:
http://www.btw-2015.de/res/proceedings/Hauptband/Wiss/Neumann-Unnesting_Arbitrary_Querie.pdf

Comment: The final query is more complicated than what I needed help with. I just had to hear about "distinct" first to get on the right track. But like I said, more complicated. Have to do another post now on how to do it, even though I think I'm really close.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT posts.*, comments.last_one
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT MAX(updated) as last_one, post_id
  FROM comments
  GROUP BY post_id
 ) as comments
ON comments.post_id = posts.id
ORDER BY comments.last_one DESC
```